# JS: Return value from EventListener function

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to return an array of instances of my Class. However the return is simply returning from the `window.addEventListener('load', function(){} );` function I believe. As when I type `plugins` into the control it is undefined.

```
;class Parallax {

    constructor(node) {

        // Settings and defaults
        // this.settings = {
        //     container: null,
        //     panels: [],
        //     defaultSpeed: 0.5
        // };

    }

    static initialize() {

        // Ensure DOM has loaded
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            // Does page contain any parallax panels?
            let panels = document.querySelectorAll('[data-parallax]');
            if (panels.length > 0) {

                let instances = [];

                // Parallax panels found, create instances of class and return them for reference
                for (const panel in panels) {
                    if (panels.hasOwnProperty(panel)) {
                        instances.push(new this(panels[panel]));
                    }
                }

                return instances;
            } else {
                // Page doesn't appear to have Parallax
                return false;
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
window.plugins = { "parallax-instances": Parallax.initialize() };
```

Not too sure how to go about doing this, I have tried assigning the `window.addEventListener` to a variable, however that doesn't return the value. I am retaining the class scope by binding `this` to my function call within the event listener.

**Edit:**
I did want to start the plugin by simply having the below code, however not too sure how to return possible multiple instances of the class as of course doing the below runs the `constructor` method first.

```
window.plugins = { "parallax-instances": new Parallax };
```

**Edit 2**
If I return the instances outside of the EventListener I get my desired result. However this could potentially return `instances` before the page has loaded right?

```
static initialize() {

        this.instances = [];

        // Ensure DOM has loaded
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            // Does page contain any parallax panels?
            let panels = document.querySelectorAll('[data-parallax]');
            if (panels.length > 0) {

                // Parallax panels found, create instances of class and return them for reference
                for (const panel in panels) {
                    if (panels.hasOwnProperty(panel)) {
                        this.instances.push(new this(panels[panel]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }.bind(this));

        return this.instances;
    }
```

What I get in the console:

```
{parallax-instances: Array(2)}
    parallax-instances:Array(2)
        0:Parallax {}
        1:Parallax {}
        length:2
    __proto__:Array(0)
    __proto__:Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `initialize` is not returning anything. If you elevate `instances` to outside your event listener and return that, you can remove the other `return` statements. **Note that the returned array will be empty until the callback is actually called (after `load`).**

```
static initialize() {

    const instances = [];

    window.addEventListener( "load", () => {

        const panels = document.querySelectorAll( "[data-parallax]" );
        for ( let i = 0; i < panels.length; i++ )
            instances.push( new this( panels[ i ] ) );

    });

    return instances;

}
```

Since you would be returning an array right away, your false syntax would disappear and you'd test `.length === 0` instead. You can get the behavior you specified using a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) instead.

Comment: Your above code is what I have used before, are you saying this is the correct way? As couldn't the `return instances;` potentially run before the load callback executes? As the code would continue to run past the event listener right?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is *the* correct way, but rather *a* correct way. The `return instances;` will certainly run before the callback executes. But the array is passed via reference and will populate eventually. That means anything that wants to use the array should also wait. If you want to ensure they only get a populated array, you'd need to implement a callback (or promise) syntax (i.e., make `initialize` accept a function that is invoked with a populated `instances`).

Answer (score 3):

An event listener function is a callback, and runs only when the event happens (in your case, on load).

Callbacks cannot return a value. You could use a variable in the outer scope (e.g. within your class), and reassign it within your event listener.

E.g.

```
constructor () {
  this.instances = []
}
```

And then (instead of returning from your event listener):

```
this.instances = instances
```

Comment: Assigning instance to the constructor won't really help though, as I need to return the instances of the class created to `window.plugins`. I have done this before outside of the eventListener, see updated post.

Comment: So you could just assign to `window.plugins` within your event listener, right?