# Why are my data getter functions returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to use Google API to get the lat/lng of an address grabbed from a spreadsheet and return the output into the HTML table. I'm not sure what to put in the getLat & getLong functions as they return "undefined". Below is my code:

```
function getCoords(tableID)
{
var oTable = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

var tblHeadObj = document.getElementById(tableID).tHead;
var newTH = document.createElement('th');
tblHeadObj.rows[0].appendChild(newTH);
newTH.innerHTML = 'Latitude'
var newTH2 = document.createElement('th');
tblHeadObj.rows[0].appendChild(newTH2);
newTH2.innerHTML = 'Longitude'

var tblBodyObj = document.getElementById(tableID).tBodies[0];
for (var i=0; i<tblBodyObj.rows.length; i++) {
    for (k = 1; k < rowLength; k++){
        var oCells = oTable.rows.item(k).cells;
        var cellLength = oCells.length;
        var totalVal = '';

        for(var j = 2; j < cellLength; j++){
            var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;        
            var newCell = tblBodyObj.rows[i].insertCell(-1);
            var newCell2 = tblBodyObj.rows[i].insertCell(-1);
            var value = cellVal + ' ';
            totalVal = totalVal + value;
        }
        newCell.innerHTML = getLat(totalVal);
        newCell2.innerHTML = getLong(totalVal);
        i++;
    }
    }
}

function getLat(tableVal){
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(tableVal);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
      document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat;
      return lat;
    });
  }
  
function getLong(tableVal){
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(tableVal);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
      document.getElementById("longitude").value = lng;
      return lng;
    });
}
```

Comment: These functions don't make much sense, because they only just add new `place_changed` event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are returning *inside* the anonymous `addEventListener` callback. Instead, create a variable in your `getLat` and `getLon` functions, assign the return value inside the callback function to these variables, and return the variables in the `getLat` and `getLon` functions.

```js
function getLong(tableVal) {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(tableVal);
    var retval = 0;
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
      document.getElementById("longitude").value = lng;
      retval = lng;
    });
    return retval;
}
```

There are some issues with that way; read more about them in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340344/js-return-value-from-eventlistener-function)'s answers.

Answer (score 0):

The guy up of me said the real thing, you're returning the required value to the anonymous function callback passed as argument to `google.maps.event.addListener(...)`. Seems your function behaves asynchronously and a way to return the value while you don't change a lot your code is using Promises. set your functions to return a Promise which only resolves inside your callback, and prepend in your code using those functions the `await` keyword to the runtime wait the promise to be resolved (or rejected) and get the desired value. Notice that you can only use `await` inside `async` context, so if it does not suits you then you can use the `Promise.then(...)` and/or `Promise.catch(...)` methods on the Promise returned by each function passing to those methods an callback to deal with the resolved and rejected context of your promise (there you'll get your desired value to do whatever you want).

Code example:

```
function example(arg) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //code...
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', ((resolve, reject) => function (){
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
            document.getElementById("longitude").value = lng;
            resolve(lng);
        })(resolve, reject));
    });
}

example()
.then(function (lng){
    // Do whatever you want with your lng
}).catch(function (reason) {
    // If you use anywhere the `reject` callback of promise, that'll lead you here in
    // catch callback, or in second callback argument of `.then()` if you return another
    // promise inside `.then()` callback.
});

// ...

async function foo(){
    // ...

    // Be careful with rejections using await. await forces rejections
    // to throw exceptions so be sure to handle them with `try..catch` blocks.
    let lng = await example();

    // ...
}
```

The code above uses Promises to keep asynchronous behavior with ease and Closures to ensure the context of the Promise to the anonymous callback used inside the Promise.